FireDAC behaving indeterministically at a specific customer's environment
I'm encountering intermittent errors in a Delphi application that uses FireDAC with SQLite, specifically configured in Delphi 10 Seattle.
This problem is particularly perplexing as it only occurs for one specific customer, displaying seemingly indeterminate behavior. Typically, the system resumes normal function after a restart, but the problem unpredictably recurs later. We have been unable to reproduce these errors internally. They were only identified through the use of EurekaLog.
Configuration of TFDConnection:

Normal locking is enabled to support access by multiple processes.
Write-Ahead Logging is enabled.
(LockWait := True) Lock waiting is enabled, allowing transactions to wait for locks to be released.
(lmPessimistic) Pessimistic locking is used as required by LockWait.

Two processes access the database concurrently: typically, one writes while the other reads. There are no heavy loads, and concurrent writing attempts, which are very rare, are managed effectively by the lockwait setting.
The examples shown here pertain exclusively to read operations.
Questions

Could the specific configuration settings like Locking Mode, WAL, or others contribute to these errors?
Are there any adjustments to the FireDAC or SQLite parameters that might help stabilize the application under high-load conditions or specific environmental factors? (AutoClose, BeforeClose?)

Example 1 - Fetching rows
Goal:
Fetch a sorted list of SOP instance UIDs using a prepared statement with one variable.
  Query := FQuerySortImagesByInstanceNoAsc;
  try
    begin
      Query.ParamByName('series_iuid').Value := SeriesInstanceUID;
      Query.Open;
      while not Query.Eof do
      begin
        SopInstUIDs.Add(Query.FieldByName(...).AsString);
        Query.Next;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Query.Close;
  end;

It failed at Query.Next.
ExceptionClass: EFDException
ExceptionMessage: [FireDAC][Phys][SQLITE]-311. Command must be open for fetching.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Methods |Details|Stack           |Address         |Module      |Offset          |Unit                |Class                   |Procedure/Method    |Line      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*Exception Thread: ID=136748; Parent=131140; Priority=0                                                                                                       |
|Class=TQueryThread; Name=[Unnamed thread] Kind: TThread. Thread function: ...
|DeadLock=0; Wait Chain=                                                                                                                                       |
|Comment=                                                                                                                                                      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|7FFFFFFE|04     |0000000000000000|0000000000EC87A7|App.exe |0000000000AC87A7|FireDAC.Stan.Error  |                        |FDException         |189[27]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27EF68|000000000107C1B1|App.exe |0000000000C7C1B1|FireDAC.Phys        |TFDPhysCommand          |FetchBase           |8661[17]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F018|000000000107B804|App.exe |0000000000C7B804|FireDAC.Phys        |TFDPhysCommandAsyncFetch|Execute             |8540[1]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F048|00000000010AAACA|App.exe |0000000000CAAACA|FireDAC.Stan.Async  |TFDStanAsyncExecutor    |ExecuteOperation    |175[6]    |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F0A8|00000000010AAFE5|App.exe |0000000000CAAFE5|FireDAC.Stan.Async  |TFDStanAsyncExecutor    |Run                 |270[12]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F158|0000000001070964|App.exe |0000000000C70964|FireDAC.Phys        |TFDPhysCommand          |ExecuteTask         |6575[21]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F1E8|000000000107C919|App.exe |0000000000C7C919|FireDAC.Phys        |TFDPhysCommand          |Fetch               |8751[2]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F268|00000000010F302E|App.exe |0000000000CF302E|FireDAC.Comp.Client |TFDCustomCommand        |Fetch               |7032[11]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F388|00000000010F54A7|App.exe |0000000000CF54A7|FireDAC.Comp.Client |TFDCustomTableAdapter   |Fetch               |7801[3]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F3C8|00000000010FAB3E|App.exe |0000000000CFAB3E|FireDAC.Comp.Client |TFDAdaptedDataSet       |DoFetch             |9957[3]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F408|00000000010C1CB2|App.exe |0000000000CC1CB2|FireDAC.Comp.DataSet|TFDDataSet              |InternalFetchRows   |4485[25]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F488|00000000010BF0C5|App.exe |0000000000CBF0C5|FireDAC.Comp.DataSet|TFDDataSet              |GetRecord           |3551[16]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F4D8|0000000000EBA653|App.exe |0000000000ABA653|Data.DB             |TDataSet                |GetNextRecord       |13812[9]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F518|0000000000EBB272|App.exe |0000000000ABB272|Data.DB             |TDataSet                |MoveBy              |14183[16] |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F578|0000000000EBB4CE|App.exe |0000000000ABB4CE|Data.DB             |TDataSet                |Next                |14227[3]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000D27F5A8|0000000001242159|App.exe |0000000000E42159|SQLiteConnection    |TSQLiteConnection       |SortImagesBySortType|577[26]   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

Example 2 - COUNT
Goal:
Determine the number of files that are part of the current series using a prepared statement with one variable.
  Query := FQueryGetFileCountSeries;
  try
    Query.ParamByName('series_iuid').Value := SeriesInstanceUID;
    Query.Open;
    Result := Query.Fields[0].AsInteger;
  finally
    Query.Close;
  end;

It failed at Query.Close.
ExceptionClass: EInvalidPointer
ExceptionMessage: Application made attempt to free invalid or unknown memory block: $000000000F6B02B0 DATA [?] 0 bytes.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Methods |Details|Stack           |Address         |Module      |Offset          |Unit                |Class              |Procedure/Method                   |Line       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*Exception Thread: ID=139204; Parent=0; Priority=0                                                                                                                       |
|Class=; Name=MAIN                                                                                                                                                        |
|DeadLock=0; Wait Chain=                                                                                                                                                  |
|Comment=                                                                                                                                                                 |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|7FFFFFFE|04     |0000000000000000|0000000000412285|App.exe |0000000000012285|System              |                   |_UStrClr                           |24641[8]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DC38|0000000000412342|App.exe |0000000000012342|System              |                   |_UStrArrayClr                      |24786[4]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DC78|00000000004150DA|App.exe |00000000000150DA|System              |                   |_FinalizeArray                     |31726[24]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DCC8|0000000000414FE0|App.exe |0000000000014FE0|System              |                   |_FinalizeRecord                    |31577[18]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DD18|000000000040EF1E|App.exe |000000000000EF1E|System              |TObject            |CleanupInstance                    |16368[8]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DD58|000000000040ED3B|App.exe |000000000000ED3B|System              |TObject            |FreeInstance                       |16186[1]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DD88|000000000040F82E|App.exe |000000000000F82E|System              |                   |_ClassDestroy                      |17536[1]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DDB8|0000000000E9D8F8|App.exe |0000000000A9D8F8|Data.DB             |TField             |Destroy                            |4809[9]    |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DDF8|000000000040EE65|App.exe |000000000000EE65|System              |TObject            |Free                               |16255[5]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DE28|0000000000E9CB6A|App.exe |0000000000A9CB6A|Data.DB             |TFields            |ClearBase                          |4487[14]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DE88|0000000000E9CC46|App.exe |0000000000A9CC46|Data.DB             |TFields            |ClearAutomatic                     |4506[1]    |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DEB8|0000000000EB717E|App.exe |0000000000AB717E|Data.DB             |TDataSet           |DestroyFields                      |12782[1]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DEF8|00000000010BD795|App.exe |0000000000CBD795|FireDAC.Comp.DataSet|TFDDataSet         |InternalClose                      |3068[21]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DF78|00000000010F9C93|App.exe |0000000000CF9C93|FireDAC.Comp.Client |TFDAdaptedDataSet  |InternalClose                      |9628[2]    |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DFA8|00000000010FD3BD|App.exe |0000000000CFD3BD|FireDAC.Comp.Client |TFDRdbmsDataSet    |InternalClose                      |11018[3]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014DFF8|0000000000EB631C|App.exe |0000000000AB631C|Data.DB             |TDataSet           |CloseCursor                        |12528[6]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014E038|00000000010BD03E|App.exe |0000000000CBD03E|FireDAC.Comp.DataSet|TFDDataSet         |CloseCursor                        |2939[3]    |
|00000020|04     |000000000014E078|0000000000EB60BA|App.exe |0000000000AB60BA|Data.DB             |TDataSet           |SetActive                          |12480[22]  |
|00000020|04     |000000000014E0C8|00000000010B881C|App.exe |0000000000CB881C|FireDAC.Comp.DataSet|TFDDataSet         |SetActive                          |1581[7]    |
|00000020|04     |000000000014E0F8|0000000000EB5DB1|App.exe |0000000000AB5DB1|Data.DB             |TDataSet           |Close                              |12431[1]   |
|00000020|04     |000000000014E128|000000000124D247|App.exe |0000000000E4D247|SQLiteConnection    |TSQLiteConnection  |GetFileCountSeries                 |1582[8]    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|


Does the troublesome system enters Sleep or Hibernation mode just prior the error occurs? Are database files located on physical or network drive?

The system does not enter hibernation mode and the database file is stored locally.
I just noticed something while writing this post. Could the indeterministic behavior possibly be related to the fact that in this case one query is not executed in the main thread?

Using threads is not normally a problem with Firedac, but you must use them sensibly.  For example are you certain that another thread is not interfering with the shared connection?  Typically I ensure that only one thread is accessing the database at a time.  You could try System.TMonitor.Enter(Connection) coupled with System.Tmonitor.Exit(Connection) to implement thread ownership of the connection.

Our TSQLiteConnection class is a singleton, with the TFDConnection as a private field, meaning the entire executable always has only one open connection at any time. All prepared statements (TFDQuery) are also private fields, and there is exactly one instance of each statement. This could potentially lead to a scenario where the dataset is being read in one thread while it is being closed in the other one, resulting in exceptions when it tries to fetch the next row. The codebase is legacy and typically doesn't operate multithreaded, which is likely why this issue was overlooked.

Also know that you can not share a TFDConnection between threads. You need a new connection for each thread.

This is a great point and was indeed an issue with the second process that writes to the SQLite database. In that implementation, each thread has its own connection. However, as mentioned, the process in question does not usually operate with multithreading. This one query was an exception, which is why it was initially overlooked. We are talking about hundreds of thousands of lines. I've now moved the relevant calls to the main thread using TThread.Synchronize. I am currently awaiting customer feedback to confirm if this resolves the issue. I'll keep you updated.

The error seems to be fixed.

I moved the relevant calls to the main thread using TThread.Synchronize, which resolved the issue.
